# TCPDF very slow generation of dynamic arabic PDF

Tags: php, iis, tcpdf

I've been using a combination of nusoap & TCPDF to ping a web service and dynamically fill out a PDF with content.

The PDF itself (in english) takes around 8-9 seconds to complete for about 36 pages, some of which include bar charts.  I'd also like to note that due to the format that the data is received in, I am using "writeHTML" to present it on the PDF.

My major issue came around when I started trying to generate the same PDFs with arabic translations.  I'm using the "Almohanad" font as described in the TCPDF examples, and the processing time jumped up to 2 minutes.

I've tried using the following fix (which caches font files) : http://www.bitrealm.net/2010/08/tcpdf-is-slow-here-is-the-solution/

Alas it did not seem to work (the ".CACHED" file didn't appear even though I gave the tcpdf file full user permissions)!  I do have to mention that i needed to insert ob_clean() after the "require_once" section of my php file to avoid the following error:

"TCPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF"

I checked my php files for white space and found nothing out of place.

In conclusion, could anyone help me speed up the generation of the arabic PDF using TCPDF, or else recommend a quicker alternative?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Update: To avoid the "TCPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF" make sure your document is not saved in "UTF-8" format, otherwise you will need to include "ob_clean();" somewhere in your code before the "$pdf->Output();".

Comment: To allow the linked solution to work you must not disable "setFontSubsetting", in your php file.  I'm currently seeking a way to add arabic characters to the solution.

Comment: It seems that all my problems stem from rendering the arabic font "Almohanad" - I can generate a french document, in similar time frames to an english one.

The arabic pdf code uses "pdf->setRTL()" on a number of occasions to switch between arabic and english.  I suspect this could be one of my problems.

If anyone has any ideas on how to speed up the arabic generation let me know, otherwise I'll continue updating this thread in the hope my eventual solutions help save someone the time it has cost me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the latest TCPDF version, the almohanad was replaced by aefurat and aealarabiya fonts.

The latest TCPDF version automatically convert fonts into TCPDF format using the addTTFfont() method, so you can easily add new arabic fonts as on the example below:

```
// convert TTF font to TCPDF format and store it on the fonts folder
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/path-to-font/FontName.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
// use the font
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);
```

Check also the http://projects.arabeyes.org website for alternative Arabic fonts and the http://www.tcpdf.org website for the new fonts guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mPDF](http://mpdf1.com) as an alternative it is very easy to use and it amazingly supports RTL languages like Arabic, Hebrew, Farsi/Persian, Urdu and Pashto. And [this is an example](http://mpdf1.com/examples/example_RTL.pdf) demonstrates that.