# How to change the number in TCPDF for arabic & persian numbers

Tags: php, tcpdf

How to change the number in TCPDF for arabic & persian numbers, do I need to change the encoding or char codes?

I need to replace `1` with `۱` , which is arabic code in unicode.

I find this code,But I do not know how to use it

```
function formatPageNumber($num) {
$strnum = strval($num);
$strnum = preg_replace_callback("/[0-9]/", create_function('$matches', '
$numarr = array("۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹");
return $numarr[intval($matches[0])];'), $strnum);
return $strnum;
}
```

Comment: Why you not use an arabic font? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080669/tcpdf-very-slow-generation-of-dynamic-arabic-pdf

Comment: These are not Arabic, but Persian numerals and would not be found in any Arabic font.

Comment: Ok, in that case see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

function formatPageNumber($num) {
$strnum = strval($num);
$strnum = preg_replace_callback("/[0-9]/", create_function('$matches', '
$numarr = array("۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹");
return $numarr[intval($matches[0])];'), $strnum);
return $strnum;
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();   

// define some HTML content with style
$html = formatPageNumber("This is my test string number 1724");

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Hi, OK, but if I want to write Persian text, direction was broken

Comment: This is just an example, you could put the function only in numbers that you want convert, something like this: $html = 'This is my test string number ' . formatPageNumber('1724');

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with this way
for example:

```
$num=123464;
$char=[
'0'=>'0',
'1'=>'1',
'2'=>'2',
'3'=>'3',
'4'=>'4',
'5'=>'5',
'6'=>'6',
'7'=>'7',
'8'=>'8',
'9'=>'9'];

$num=str_replace(array_keys($char),array_values($char),$num);
```

pay attention before write do this
also you can convert in footer number with this way in formatPageNumber